# Sync API for iOS, manage large files

Tags: ios, dropbox-api, large-data

I try to handle large files using Sync API for iOS

My program encrypts files in the stream, and I record the encrypted part (at ~ 320000 bytes) method

```
[file appendData: data error: nil];
```

file - variable format DBFile

data - variable format NSData, have size ~320000 bytes

When the file size reaches 80 MB program takes off and does not give an error
In the course of the program produces errors recieve memory warning, although no additional variables are not used

What are some ways to manage large files to dropbox api for ios (and download too)? Or what's my problem here?